# I need the metadata from a mysql resultset, is this possible?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'd like to obtain the metadata from the results of a mysql query so I can put it into a datatable in c#. I primarily need the column name and the data type. Here's a simple example.

```
show columns from (
 select sum(subtotal) as subtotal
 , sum(tax1+tax2+tax3+tax4) as tax
 , sum(subtotal)+sum(tax1+tax2+tax3+tax4) as total

 from tbltransmaster 
 where batchnum in (
  SELECT BatchNum
  FROM tblshiftmaster

  WHERE ClosingTS <> -1

  ORDER BY OpeningTS ASC
 )
) as x
```

It generates this error though

> Error Code : 1064 You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(
>
> select sum(subtotal) as subtotal
>
> , sum(tax1+tax2+tax3+tax4) as tax
>
> , sum' at line 1

Could someone provide me with some advice, or perhaps a link to assist with this?

Comment: Which database driver/provider/connector you are using?

Most drivers have their own methods of metadata access. 
After executing a query, you probbaly want to call some method on the query object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

show columns only works for actual tables and views, not for queries.

Since you mention C#, you're probably using ADO.NET ? You can directly fill a DataTable which figure out the data types and column names.

```
DbConnection conn = null;
DbConnection conn = null;
DbCommand cmd = null;
DbDataAdapter da = null;
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();

cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = query;

da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(tbl);
```

If you want to get the colum names only, you could fetch the result using a DataReader instead:

```
DbDataReader dbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
for (int i = 0; i < dbReader.FieldCount; i++) {
  Type colType = dbReader.GetFieldType(i);
  String colName = dbReader.GetName(i);
}
```

DbDataReader also have the .GetSchemaTable() which returns a DataTable describing the metadata of the result.